# derby.properties file in java.util.Properties.save method

Tags: java, derby

I am struggling to figure out how to create a Derby.Properties file with the  java.util.Properties.save method. Right now I have created a file with the following snippet below inside and I named it derby.properties and placed it in the "/Users/computer/db-derby-10.5.1.1-bin" folder as well as the "/Users/computer/db-derby-10.5.1.1-bin/bin" folder but it doesn't seem to work. The file appears to be in text format I wonder if I need to change it to the right format or have I placed it in the right directory.

```
derby.connection.requireAuthentication=true
#
derby.authentication.provider=BUILTIN
#
# Users definition
#
derby.user.sa=derbypass
derby.user.exampleperson=examplepasswd
derby.database.readOnlyAccessUsers=exampleperson
derby.database.fullAccessUsers=sa
derby.database.defaultConnectionMode=readOnlyAccess
```

Link to website instructions:
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/tuning/ctunsetprop13074.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: The format looks fine, but it sounds like you are putting it in the wrong directory. BTW, you're apparently using Derby 10.5 and reading the Derby 10.2 docs, so you might want to move up to the current release. Check https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevsetprop13074.html and https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevdvlp27610.html#cdevdvlp27610

Comment: If you can share your JDBC Connection URL, and also whether you are using client-server or embedded mode, we could probably help you further.

Comment: Thanks. I did place it in the wrong directory and it's working now.